# React state not changing in component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router

I'm trying to create protected routes that are only viable while user is logged in, but I have trouble getting loggedIn state in ProtectedRoutes component, it's always set to false thus redirecting to "/login". What am I not getting correctly here?

**App.tsx**

```
interface loginContextInterface {
    loggedIn: boolean;
    setLoggedIn: (value: (((prevState: boolean) => boolean) | boolean)) => void;
}

export const LoginContext = createContext({} as loginContextInterface);

export default function App() {
    const [ loggedIn, setLoggedIn ] = useState(false)

     useEffect(() => {
        console.log("before", loggedIn)
        isLoggedIn().then((r) => {
            console.log("R", r)
            setLoggedIn(r)
        })
        console.log("after", loggedIn)
    }, [loggedIn])

    return (
        <LoginContext.Provider value={{loggedIn, setLoggedIn}}>
            <Router>
                <MenuHeader />
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
                    <Route path="/tasks" element={<ProtectedRoutes/>}>
                        <Route path="/" element={<Tasks/>}/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}/>
                    <Route path="/logout" element={<Logout />}/>
                    <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>}/>
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </LoginContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

**ProtectedRoutes.tsx**

```
export const ProtectedRoutes = () =>{
    const location = useLocation();
    const {loggedIn} = useContext(LoginContext)

    console.log("protected", loggedIn)

    return (
        loggedIn ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to={"/login"} replace state={{location}}/>
    );
}
```

**Edit:**

isLoggedIn just authenticates that the user is logged in via cookie using api on the server side. Added logging

Produces these after trying to access /tasks route and redirecting me to /login again

```
VM109:236 protected false
App.tsx:21 before false
App.tsx:26 after false
App.tsx:21 before false
App.tsx:26 after false
2App.tsx:23 R true
App.tsx:21 before true
App.tsx:26 after true
App.tsx:23 R true
```

Comment: What does `isLoggedIn` return? When is the `loggedIn` state updated to anything other than false? Can you share all relevant code as part of your [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to reset the dependency inside the useEffect(), it may cause an infinite loop.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // loggedIn will be update here and trigger the useEffect agan
  isLoggedIn().then((r) => setLoggedIn(r)) 
}, [loggedIn])
```

What does the `console.log(loggedIn) and console.log(r)`  show? I'm guessing isLoggedIn returns false, loggedIn is set to false initially so useEffect not being triggered again and it remains as `false`

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the `useEffect` hook, using the `loggedIn` state value as the dependency. You should not use dependencies that are unconditionally updated by the hook callback. My guess here is that you wanted to do an initial authentication check when the app mounts. You can remove `loggedIn` from the dependency since it's not referenced at all.

```
useEffect(() => {
  isLoggedIn().then(setLoggedIn);
}, []);
```

I suggest also using an initial `loggedIn` state value that doesn't match either the authenticated or unauthenticated states, i.e. something ***other than*** `true|false`. This is so the `ProtectedRoutes` can conditionally render null or some loading indicator while any pending authentication checks are in-flight and there isn't any confirmed authentication state already saved in state.

Update the context to declare `loggedIn` optional.

```
interface loginContextInterface {
  loggedIn?: boolean;
  setLoggedIn: React.Dispatch<boolean>;
}
```

Update `App` to have an initially undefined `loggedIn` state value.

```
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState<boolean | undefined>();
```

Update `ProtectedRoutes` to check for the undefined `loggedIn` state to render a loading indicator and ***not*** immediately bounce the user to the login route.

```
const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { loggedIn } = useContext(LoginContext);

  if (loggedIn === undefined) {
    return <>Checking authentication...</>; // example
  }

  return loggedIn ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to={"/login"} replace state={{ location }} />
  );
};
```

Also in `App`, remove/move the `"/tasks"` path from the layout route rendering the `ProtectedRoutes` component to the nested route rendering the `Tasks` component. The reason is that it's invalid to nest the absolute path `"/"` in `"/tasks"`.

```
<Route element={<ProtectedRoutes />}>
  <Route path="/tasks" element={<Tasks />} />
</Route>
```

[image: Edit react-state-not-changing-in-component]